# Reading API response

Tags: php

I have the following response in `$response` which I am trying to read:

```
Response Object
(
    [errorMessage] => 
    [errorType] => 
    [statusCode] => 200
    [response] => {"success":false}
    [success] => 1
)
```

I can get each key using `$response->keyName`

for example, i can get the status code by echoing `$response->statusCode`

But im not sure how to get the response object.

`$response->response->success`

which returned nothing and also

`$response->response["success"]`

which just returned `{`

Comment: Did you try to use `var_dump($response->response->success)`. What is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you json decode `[response] => {"success":false}` this

```
 $a= json_decode($response->response);
```

and finally you can get

```
print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

`response` is a JSON string, you need to use `json_decode()` to parse it.

```
json_decode($response->response)->success;
```